# Does this fill valve need replacing or should I replace cap? Its leaking

Tags: toilet

This fill valve is leaking, I have flushed it and it still leaks. Does it look okay or does the entire assembly need replacing?[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This is a fill valve on a what? And, what make and model?

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine, but what about the diaphragm/washer assembly? That is the stuff that gets soft and worn over time; you most certainly should replace that if ever you open up the cap...